# how to remove sticky header and keep it static

Tags: javascript, css, html, scroll, sticky

I am currently working on this site - http://andersontreesurgery.co.uk/. I used html5 up template and the template already had a sticky header. However when the site is scaled down a gap is created between the header and the banner which looks bad. Also I just dont want the header to move down and always stay at the top on top of everything.

The mobile menu I still like as it slides out, however how do I stop the sticky header without remove any other function?

Thanks,

Gemma

Comment: You should edit your question to give more details (also a link or two) to the HTML/CSS libraries you're using.

Comment: This is a css question mostly.. and edging into UI/UX area.. at least some code will be needed to answer.. but your question needs to be more specific

Comment: Check `position: fixed` and `z-index: 9999` for the header.

Answer (score 2):

This would help

```js
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(winTop >= 30){
      $("body").addClass("sticky-header");
    }else{
      $("body").removeClass("sticky-header");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
position:fixed 
z-index:9999

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
/* For Extra styling try this */
body.sticky-header{
    padding-top: 100px;
    header{
        height: 60px;
        h1{
            @include scale(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sach, thanks for your reply. Where would I put this code? I dont have a functions.php file.

Comment: Hi Gemma, Hope you are doing good...It is just a JS file which is doing the transition. so forget about functions.php.  create the JS file as per the 1st block of code and add the CSS position property as mentioned and it should work.